# MySQL - Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-python, mariadb-10.1

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.44-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

`ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 8613: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Line 8613: `INSERT INTO puffle_item (id, parent_id, name, type, play_external, cost, quantity, member, food_effect, rest_effect, play_effect, clean_effect) VALUES`

Table it's referring to:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS puffle_item;
CREATE TABLE puffle_item (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  parent_id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'care',
  play_external VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'none',
  cost INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  quantity SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  member BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
  food_effect SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  rest_effect SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  play_effect SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  clean_effect SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT puffle_item_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES puffle_item (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Example of item trying to put in the table:
`(1, 1, 'Brush', 'care', 'none', 0, 1, FALSE, -2, -2, 5, 5),`

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to disable the constraint, because parent id 1 doesn't exist, at the time you try to enter that row.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE puffle_item (
>   id INT NOT NULL,
>   parent_id INT NOT NULL,
>   name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>   type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'care',
>   play_external VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'none',
>   cost INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
>   quantity SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
>   member BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
>   food_effect SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
>   rest_effect SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
>   play_effect SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
>   clean_effect SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
>   PRIMARY KEY (id),
>   CONSTRAINT puffle_item_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES puffle_item (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
> );
> ```

> ```
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
>
> INSERT INTO puffle_item (id, parent_id, name, type, play_external, cost, quantity, member, food_effect, rest_effect, play_effect, clean_effect) VALUES (1, 1, 'Brush', 'care', 'none', 0, 1, FALSE, -2, -2, 5, 5);
>
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
> ```

> ```
> select * from puffle_item
> ```
>
> ```
> id | parent_id | name  | type | play_external | cost | quantity | member | food_effect | rest_effect | play_effect | clean_effect
> -: | --------: | :---- | :--- | :------------ | ---: | -------: | -----: | ----------: | ----------: | ----------: | -----------:
>  1 |         1 | Brush | care | none          |    0 |        1 |      0 |          -2 |          -2 |           5 |            5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=cb2a31fb66d860db542a564436b766aa)*

Comment: there was a missing semicolon at the end i corrected it